# Facebook Graph API Search Places

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to know how can I use Facebook Search API to get the results similar to the web page...I'm familiar with Facebook Graph API but couldn't get results similar to the web page search...

[You can view the web page search here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F4Wn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can never get the same results, the search api only offers a small amount of what you can do with Graph Search. Please read the docs about what is possible with the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search